# Set Name to Bean with value method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

Is there any difference in setting a name to a bean while using value or name method of bean annotation.

```
@Configuration
public class OperationConfig {

    @Bean(name = "test")
    public IOperation getOperation()
    {
         return new IntMultiplyOperation();
    }
}
```

or

```
@Configuration
public class OperationConfig {

    @Bean("test")
    public IOperation getOperation()
    {
         return new IntMultiplyOperation();
    }
}
```

Spring can catch both of them with this constructor

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationRunnerConfig {
    private final IOperation m_operation;

    public ApplicationRunnerConfig(@Qualifier("test") IOperation operation)
    {
        m_operation = operation;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotation without any field reference maps to value attribute and as in @Bean annotation value is alias for name both ways are identical.

Check for more information
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between these methods. Spring by default sets string param in brackets as the name param.

Answer (score 1):

they do the same thing. take a look at `@Bean` interface file:

```
public @interface Bean {
    @AliasFor("name")
    String[] value() default {};

    @AliasFor("value")
    String[] name() default {};
}
```

they use `@AliasFor` which is a Spring annotation indicating that these attributes can be used interchangeably.